# Вложение в команду update рекурсивного запроса

Tags: sql-server

Есть некоторая сложность вложить в команду update рекурcивный запрос. Например, есть вот такой запрос:

```
update [UMU].[dbo].[DISCIPLINE_CHAIR]

set [UMU].[dbo].[DISCIPLINE_CHAIR].[chair_id] =

(

with cte as 
(...)

select max(chair_id) as chair_id 
from cte

)

where  [UMU].[dbo].[DISCIPLINE_CHAIR].[CHAIR_ID] in 
(
    ...
)
```

Ругается на конструкцию with cte, вложенную в set команды update. Пробовал результаты рекурсивного запроса записать в переменную ( set [@id](/users/3123/idanil) = ( ... ) ), но безрезультатно, ругается на синтаксис. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with cte нужно писать ПЕРЕД запросом, а не внутри него.
Еще одно замечание - с точки зрения данных, нет никаких препятствий к тому, чтобы последний номер chair_id был бы обязательно выше, чем один из промежуточных, т.е. он может быть сначала 600, а потом - 45, выбирая max(), вы всегда получите максимальное значение, а не последнее. Поэтому лучше выбирать записи с IsActive=1.

```
with 
cte as 
(
  select distinct dc.[chair_id] as [original_chair_id], dc.[chair_id] as [new_chair_id], c.[IsActive]
    from [UMU].[dbo].[DISCIPLINE_CHAIR] as dc
         inner join [UMU].[dbo].[CHAIR] as с
                 on dc.chair_id = c.chair_id
  union all
  select cte.[original_chair_id] as [original_chair_id], c.[chair_id] as [new_chair_id], c.[IsActive]
    from [UMU].[dbo].[CHAIR] as с
         inner join cte 
                 on с.[HISTORY_LINK] = cte.new_chair_id
)
update dc
   set [chair_id] =
         (select new_chair_id as chair_id 
            from cte 
           where cte.original_char_id = dc.char_id
             and cte.IsActive = 1)
 where [UMU].[dbo].[DISCIPLINE_CHAIR].[CHAIR_ID] as dc in 
    (...)
```

Comment: Ага,понятно.Правда есть 1 проблема : у меня сам рекурсвиный запрос зависит от [UMU].[dbo].[DISCIPLINE_CHAIR].[chair_id], который используется  командой update (блок set). Поэтому ,наверное, в моем случае вынести этот запрос нельзя . Хотя может чего-то недопонял.

Comment: судя по тому, что cte у вас используется только для "select max(chair_id) as chair_id from cte", cte вам не нужен. Просто пишете в самом подзапросе "select max(...) from ... where smth = DISCIPLINE_CHAIR.smth group by ..." Ну и вынести можно всегда, вы cte можете построить по всем значениям, а в подзапросе объединить его с вышестоящей таблицей, чтобы получить только релевантные строки. Трудно объяснить понятнее на неконкретном примере, если остались вопросы - формулируйте изначальную полную задачу с описанием таблиц.

Comment: Если можно, наверное тогда один кусок кода приведу (почти тот же самый рекурсивный запрос ,что вы мне писали)(содержимое блока set):

with cte as 
(select [UMU].[dbo].[CHAIR].[chair_id] from [UMU].[dbo].[CHAIR]
 where  [UMU].[dbo].[CHAIR].[chair_id] = 
 [UMU].[dbo].[DISCIPLINE_CHAIR].[chair_id] 
 
 union all
 
 select [UMU].[dbo].[CHAIR].[chair_id]
   from [UMU].[dbo].[CHAIR]
        inner join cte
        on [UMU].[dbo].[CHAIR].[HISTORY_LINK] = cte.chair_ID)  

Тут как раз [UMU].[dbo].[DISCIPLINE_CHAIR].[chair_id] и есть зависимость от блока set . С этим вся сложность.

Comment: Внес изменения в ответ.